# How do you debug in an Andorid phone that is not a Nexus?

Tags: usb-debugging, usb-drivers

I am trying to hook up my LG818P to chrome developer tools. In the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html) it says to download the firmware form the OEM's website, yet every step after installing said usb driver assumes you have a **Nexus device.**

The instruction include updating your mobile phone driver from /extras/google/usb_driver, which is a [package that explicitly says is applicable to Nexus devices](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html). The documentation is too vague for me to spot a proper solution.

Comment: The documentation is just fine. You need to find the OEM USB Drivers from [this list](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Drivers), then follow the instructions by replacing the path to the downloaded files.

Comment: After pulling many hairs I discovered it LG4 requires you to change the USB connection from MTP to PTP.

Obviously this little fact was missing from the docs.